# Entity Framework Core - storing action delegate

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core. I have entity with action delegate property:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Action<string, int, decimal, int> RateAction { get; set; }
}

var student1 = new Student();
student1.Id = 1;
student1.Name = "Test 1";
student1.RateAction = (s, a, b, c) =>
{
  var m = a * c + b;
  s = $"{s} - {m}";
};

var student2 = new Student();
student1.Id = 2;
student1.Name = "Test 2";
student1.RateAction = (s, a, b, c) =>
{
  b = c * b / a;
};
```

Student entity is part Entity Framework context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have fluent API configuration for the entity:

```
public class StudentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Student");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

        // Add config for RateAction property
    }
}
```

How store RateAction property in database and configure with entity framework?

Comment: Action is a Code not a Data, do you want to store IL code?

Comment: How many different kinds of action are you thinking of supporting?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I understand it. Maybe Is it possible to serialize or other variants ..

Comment: @CaiusJard enough

Comment: Too many technical challenges in such innocent question: 1) Select scripting engine, 2) store actions as script 3) After load compile delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Table for the property RateAction and in the Table Student you need a FK for RateAction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not storing the action.  Databases are for data and code is for configuring functionality/actions.  Instead, store instances of inherited Student classes, that implement the desired action/logic and return a calculated value, which can be further formatted as needed:

```
public abstract class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract decimal RateAction(int a, decimal b, int c);
}

public class MultiplyingStudent : Student
{
    public override decimal RateAction(int a, decimal b, int c) => a * c + b;
}

public class DividingStudent : Student
{
    public override decimal RateAction(int a, decimal b, int c) => c * b / a;
}
```

These child classes, and any others, will store just fine inside your DbSet of Student objects:

```
var m = new MultiplyingStudent();
var d = new DividingStudent();

...

var context = new MyContext();
context.Students.Add(m);
context.Students.Add(d);
```

EF will add a discriminator column as a way to help it turn rows back into instances once you do a select statement:

```
var x = context.Students.Select(s => s.Id == <int>);
var result = x.RateAction(<int>, <decimal>, <int>);
```